# Display image plus text using opencv

Tags: opencv

Using opencv, we can display text over an image. The standard method is

```
cv2.putText(img, "my_text", (x, y), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 0)
```

But I want to display a small icon image followed by text (in this case "my_text").

I could overlay an image over the image in this way:

```
icon_img = cv2.imread("icon.png")
icon_img1= cv2.resize(icon_img, (20,20))

x_offset=y_offset=5
img[y_offset:y_offset+icon_img1.shape[0], x_offset:x_offset+icon_img1.shape[1]] = icon_img1
```

But I want the icon to shift along with the display text.

An icon might look like this

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: To do this, you would have to manually assign pixel coordinates for the image and the text. Do you need help doing this?

Comment: @ShawnMathew: Thanks Shawn for the suggestion. I've updated the question. It will be great help if you show the process.

Comment: What do you mean *"you want the icon to shift along"*? Are you placing the icon and text at lots of different positions around the image or something?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Hi Mark, I want to display the text in video frames. So in Video the image will shift over the frame. So I want the icon to be dynamically shifting.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really possible in opencv.

Opencv has no concept of z-layers in its basic GUI, so you would be responsible for setting the location of every element in the image. Opencv's GUI was not really developed to be the interface for a full fledged application, but more for testing and development purposes. If you really want a full fledged GUI I recommend Qt or wxPython.

However, for this very basic problem, what you could do is something like

```
icon_img = cv2.imread("icon.png")
icon_img1= cv2.resize(icon_img, (20,20))
x_offset=y_offset=5
img[y_offset:y_offset+icon_img1.shape[0], x_offset:x_offset+icon_img1.shape[1]] = icon_img1

cv2.putText(img, "my_text", (x_offset+icon_img1.shape[1], y_offset+icon_img1.shape[0]), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 0)
```

This would shift the text to be placed after the image, right at the bottom right corner of the image

Comment: Thanks Shawn! I'll consider check your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain I understand what you are doing, but I gather you want to place an icon with some related text at various positions around the frame over a video, yes? And I assume you want the text to stay in the same place relative to the icon, yes?

If so, I would create a small *"piece of canvas"* (i.e. a `Mat`) just big enough for the icon and the text and place them both on it.

Then, as each frame of video arrives, create an ROI in the video frame, and use `copyTo()` to copy that little piece of canvas ontop of the video frame:

```
// define image ROI at bottom-right of video frame
cv::Mat imageROI(frame, cv::Rect(frame.cols-canvas.cols,
                                 frame.rows-canvas.rows,
                                 canvas.cols,canvas.rows));

// insert icon canvas
canvas.copyTo(imageROI);
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for your answer! Suppose there are multiple vegetable items in a video. Some are fresh vegetables, some are not. So for fresh vegetable, it will display the vegetable name with a "happy smiley". And for not so fresh, the "sad smiley" with vegetable name. Now the image of vegetable will come at different position in the frame. So I want the icon to be dynamic. I'll try your solution. Not sure if it's can be converted into python code. I'm not familiar with c++. THanks again!